# How to change font family in vscode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I was able to change the font but it's applied only to window titles and explorer sections but the font in the editor is not reflecting the font I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If editing `settings.json`, the setting you're looking for is `"editor.fontFamily"`; if editing through the GUI, look for the section `Text Editor -> Font`.